# How does a node get added in a linked list and become its new head?

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

```
public void Add(Node<T> newItem)
{
    if(this.First==null)
    {
        this.First = newItem;
        this.Last = newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        newItem.next = this.First;
        this.First = newItem;
    }
    Count++;
}
```

I don't understand how the `else` block actually works. I understand that `newItem.next` points to the `First` node and then subsequently on next line we assign `newItem` to `First`. But I find it hard to see how this manipulation works and how the new node is added in case there already existed a node previously.

Comment: In the `if` block you add a node to an empty list. In the `else` block you do it for a non empty list. It is done by putting the new node before the current first one (making it the new first one).

Comment: How is this related to digital signature algorithm (DSA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help to visualise this. Let's say we already have a list with two nodes, having values 2 and 3:

```
 this
  │
  ▼
┌──────────┐
│ First: ──────────────┐
└──────────┘           ▼
                    ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
                    │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
                    │ next: ─────► │ next:null│
                    └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Now `newItem` is created, having value 1:

```
 this
  │
  ▼
┌──────────┐
│ First: ──────────────┐
└──────────┘           ▼
     ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
     │ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
     │ next:null│   │ next: ─────► │ next:null│
     └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
       ▲
       │
      newItem
```

Note that at this stage, this `newItem` is not part of a linked list chain. That is what a call to `Add(newItem)` will establish. When that method executes, we get in the `else` block and execute `newItem.next = this.First;`, which modifies the `next` property of this `newItem` object, so it references the same object as `this.First` references. And so we get this:

```
 this
  │
  ▼
┌──────────┐
│ First: ──────────────┐
└──────────┘           ▼
     ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
     │ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
     │ next: ─────► │ next: ─────► │ next:null│
     └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
       ▲
       │
      newItem
```

Although the node now refers to a node in the linked list, it is itself still  not part of the linked list itself. For that we need the second statement  in that `else` block: `this.First = newItem;`

The result is:

```
 this
  │
  ▼
┌──────────┐
│ First: ────┐
└──────────┘ ▼
     ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
     │ data: 1  │   │ data: 2  │   │ data: 3  │
     │ next: ─────► │ next: ─────► │ next:null│
     └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
       ▲
       │
      newItem
```

And now the goal is achieved. The list now starts with the value 1, then 2, then 3.

Answer (score 1):

`if` the list's first item is null, which means the list is empty, it set's first and the last *(since it's the only item, it will be first and the last item)* item to the `newItem`.

Or `else`, it links the first item to the new item as its next node, and sets the first item to the `newItem`. It simply puts `newItem` in the beginning of the list, then links former first item to it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bit difficult to explain without some graphics but let me give it a try.

1. Initially, our linked list is empty. **First-> NULL**
2. Then we add a new item by calling `Add`, say **Item1**.
3. Because `this.First` is null, it will start pointing to this `newItem`. Remember, `First` here is nothing but a pointer pointing to the `newItem` now.
   So our linked list now is: **First -> Item1**
4. Now we add another item but this time the linked list is not empty. Say, **Item2**
5. Looking at the code, the intention is to add the new item at the beginning of the linked list. So, we make the `next` pointer of the `newItem` point to `First` making them linked to each other. Our linked list now is: **Item2.next -> First**
6. Now because we only want to maintain the `First` (head) pointer we point it to the **current** first/ or head node which is nothing but the newly added item. Hence `this.First = newItem`.

Linked list now is: **Item2 -> Item1** with **First** pointing to **Item2**.